My Fridge is Making a Horrible Ringing Sound
As the title suggests, my fridge emits a very high-pitched ringing sound whenever it turns on, and it continues until it shuts off. It hurts my ears and bothers my headache. This is especially bothersome at night. I can't identify any specific components on the back, as it has a smooth aluminum panel with no visible parts. The brand is Amana and it is about 20 years old.
Building maintenance won't assist unless I can point them to a specific issue beyond just saying 'it's making an annoying sound.'
What could be causing this noise?

If there is a way to make a recording of the sound and post it using a file or sound sharing service, then a more accurate diagnosis might be possible. At first I guess it to be a bad bearing in the compressor motor or the freezer fan, with the age of the fridge considered. Can they not come in and listen when the fridge squeels?

Most of the things that would make the noise should be at the bottom/near the floor.

Building maintenance won't assist unless I can point them to a specific issue That's pretty crappy of them.

reminds me of a funny story, when my friend complained about his deterioriated mailbox cluster at his condo place the association ignored him.  And it went unfixed until a few days later it coincidentally was knocked over and completely non functional.

Yes unfortunately they don't stay very on top of things and don't consider this urgent. Its just ear torture
